# Update SQL statement with two conditions in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

How to put two conditions at the where clause. "Class_ID" is one of the condition

```
pendinglist.CommandText = " UPDATE Pending_List set room_status =" +
    "Still Pending" ; " Where Class_ID =
```

Comment: ...and what is the other condition?  You just want `WHERE Class_ID = <some_value> AND other_column = <some_value>`.  And you should read about prepared statements.

Comment: What is going on with your query string? You have weird concatenations for no reason, a wayward semi-colon, an unterminated string...I feel like a bot posted this question.

Comment: you just have to concat strings and yes what is going on with your query string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `and` at `where` clause:

```
   pendinglist.CommandText = " UPDATE Pending_List set room_status =" +
  "'Still Pending'" + " Where Class_ID = "+ "[your_id]" + " and room_status 
!= 'Still Pending'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code using [Prepared Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a prepared version of the command on an instance of SQL Server.

```
private static void SqlCommandPrepareEx(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);

        // Create and prepare an SQL statement.
        command.CommandText =
            "UPDATE Pending_List set room_status=@roomStatus " +
            "WHERE Class_ID=@classId AND Other=@Other";
        SqlParameter classIdParam = new SqlParameter("@classId", SqlDbType.Int, 0);
        SqlParameter OtherParam = new SqlParameter("@OtherParameter", SqlDbType.Int, 0);
        SqlParameter roomStatusParam = 
            new SqlParameter("@roomStatus", SqlDbType.Text, 100);
        classIdParam.Value = 1;
        roomStatusParam.Value = "Still Pending";
        otherParam.Value = 10;
        command.Parameters.Add(classIdParam);
        command.Parameters.Add(roomStatusParam);
        command.Parameters.Add(otherParam);

        // Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
        command.Prepare();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    }
}
```